# Apache Flink - timerService, onTimer get whole event

Tags: kotlin, apache-flink

I need some help with the timerService in Apache Flink. My use case is pretty straightforward, but I don't find any clear answer.

From a source (rabbitMQ in my case) my program receives events in json format(mapped to MyEvent, here MyEvent is simplified). Either the event is processed right away(1) or *stored* for later procession(2).
(2) I think the timerServicer ist the adequate solution. In the method onTimer I need the whole object (MyEvent) and not only the key. So first I thought using the whole json as the key, that works fine, but somehow it feels wrong, since in no example key is used that way. The second approach is the one below; using ValueState. But my key is not unique, and ValueState is per key. Again I could use an object as the key...
In onTimer I'm only able to access the key of the event in ctx.currentKey, not the event itself...

So my question: How can I store the whole event for later procession no matter what the object looks like?

This is the code (kotlin)

```
data class MyEvent(val event: String, val secs: Int)

class CountWithTimeoutFunction : KeyedProcessFunction<String, MyEvent, MyEvent>() {

    private lateinit var state: ValueState<MyEvent>

    override fun open(parameters: Configuration?) {
        state = runtimeContext.getState(ValueStateDescriptor("myState", MyEvent::class.java))
    }

    override fun processElement(myEvent: MyEvent, context: Context, collector: Collector<MyEvent>) {
        println("" + Date() + "-processElement-" + myEvent)
        state.update(myEvent)
        context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(context.timerService().currentProcessingTime() + myEvent.secs * 1000)
    }

    override fun onTimer(timestamp: Long, ctx: OnTimerContext, out: Collector<MyEvent>) {
        val myEvent = state.value()
        println("" + Date() + "-onTimer-" + ctx.currentKey + " state.value()_" + myEvent)
    }

}
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

One common, straightforward technique for cases like this is to give every event a unique key by adding a field to the events that you populate with a random number. (Note that it will **not** work to do `keyBy(random.nextLong())` because Flink relies on the keys being deterministic.)

Another technique that is sometimes used is to use `MapState`, where the key is a timer timestamp, and the value is the list of events waiting for that timer. When events arrive, append them to the list for their timestamp. When a timer fires, process everything in the list and then discard it.

This second approach will use fewer timers, but it's probably less efficient (at least with the RocksDB state backend), because of the overhead of dealing with those lists.